# How to distribute load among different spring boot microservice instances

Tags: spring-boot, load-balancing, microservices, netflix, netflix-ribbon

Say for example, can we limit the number of requests to be processed by an instance should be 50 and the rest has to be processed by another instance. 
Do we require any configuration changes related to ribbon.

Comment: Ribbon uses round-robin by default

Comment: do you mean 50 requests per seconds? or others?

Comment: Not 50 requests per second. 
I have 3 instances of a microservice, i want to process 1000 requests, i prefer only 300 requests has to be processed by first instance and next set of 300 has to be processed by second instance and third instance has to process the rest 400 requests. is it possible to configure in such a way to share the load among the instances.